# Reading and Modifying a Microsoft Word Document using TCL Script

Tags: shell, tcl

I am working on an Automation project which i coded fully in TCL. A part of the project demands to read a Microsoft Word Document and modify a line in that Word Document using TCL Script. I tried with tcom packages but i faced problem while making changes to that document since the word document gets corrupt. So guys if anybody can help me i will be very thankful.

Note : The script can also be in Shell. In that case i will invoke the shell script from my tcl script.

Thanks

Comment: I am running the TCL script from an UNIX server

Answer (score 1):

tcom is a windows only extension to allow Tcl to interact with COM objects. To automate Microsoft Word using tcom you are actually running the Word executable so this can only be done on Windows.

To do this on unix, you will need to find some unix application that can modify Word documents for you. Tcl will not have any unix extensions that can do this and the file format you have to operate on will depend on the version of Word used. If the file is a docx file then that is actually a zip format file with XML documents in it. You can use the zipvfs subcomponent of the tclvfs extension to mount the zip document and then you could use tdom (tcl XML document object model extension) to examine and modify the XML stream in place. For previous versions of word that used structured storage documents you face an uphill struggle to handle the format on non-windows systems.

Answer (score 1):

Manipulating MS Office documents on Unix is a bit of a pain, and there are no Tcl packages for doing so (as far as I know). Your best bet might be to use something like [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) for the integration work, and driving that Java library either as an external process (i.e., write a small Java app that integrates) or by running your Tcl inside a [JTcl](http://jtcl.kenai.com/) interpreter within the Java process.